# Symfony2 set entity in service arguments

Tags: php, symfony

Currently I have a form called directly into a controller . It looks like this:

```
$form = $this->CreateForm(
    new InscriptionWithPackType(
        $round,
        $this-> getUser(),
        $concours->getNbQuestions ()
    ), $inscription, array('em' => $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()));
```

The form manages a game.

The controller contains all the business logic. Not good ...
So I set out to spend all this logic in a service.

For the form, I also created a service ( inscriptionManager ) that injects FormFactoryInterface

I have a problem for the first formal parameter : `$round` ( see above ) .

Let me explain: `$round` is an entity.

I do not know what is the syntax for passing an entity argument of my service .

Comment: Please format your code in a readable way

Answer (score 0):

You should not pass an Entity into a Service.

Either inject the Entities Repository into the service, or create a seperate Method in the service that gets the entity passed like:

```
class InscriptionManager 
{
  public function __construct(your, dependencies)..

  public function doTheMagic(EntityClass $round)
  {
    // do the magic
  }
}
```

and in the controller you just call

```
// .. inside the action
$this->insrcriptionManager->doTheMagic($round);
```